# Disable RTL using ClojureScript, Re-natal and React-Native?

Tags: react-native, clojure, clojurescript, re-frame, re-natal

I'm develop an app in re-natal platform which is based on ClojureScript and React Native. I have an issue to disable RTL for my application in **Android** platform.

this is the code to disable RTL in react-native which works totally fine:

```
const ReactNative = require('react-native');

ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

And I think this is the exact above code in cljs:

```
(def ReactNative (js/require "react-native"))

(.allowRTL (.I18nManager ReactNative) false)
```

However, I got this error:

"Object is not a function (evaluating 'my-app.android.core.ReactNative.I18nManager())"

react-native: "v0.50.3"

react: "16.0.0"

re-frame: "0.9.2"

clojurescript: "1.9.542"

clojure: "1.9.0-alpha16"

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6rBy.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I18nManager` is a field (not a method) of `ReactNative` object. It should be accessed like this: `(.-I18nManager ReactNative)`. So, the equivalent of

```
ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

will be

```
(.allowRTL (.-I18nManager ReactNative) false)
```